# Computing the variance of a series of random variables

Tags: statistics, solution-verification, stochastic-processes

I have the following random variables: $U$ is distributed uniformly with variance $1/3$ and mean $0$; $G$ is distributed normally with variance $1$ and mean $0$. Both random variables are independent of one another. I have the following series: $$\frac{2}{T}\sum_{j=1}^{T/2}G_{2j}+\frac{2}{T}\sum_{i=1}^{T/2}U_{2i-1}$$

(where e.g. $G_{2j}$ means that the $2j^ { \space th}$ term is the random variable $G$—and similarily for $U_{2i-1}$).

I want to compute the variance of this series. Is the following correct?

$$\begin{array}{l}
\left(\frac{2}{T}\right)^{2} \sum_{j=1}^{T / 2} \operatorname{var}\left(G_{2 j}\right)+\left(\frac{2}{T}\right)^{2} \sum_{i=1}^{T / 2} \operatorname{var}\left(U_{2 i-1}\right)\\=
\left(\frac{2}{T}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{T}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{2}{T}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{1}{3} \frac{T}{2}\right)=\frac{2}{T}+\frac{2}{T} \frac{1}{2}=\frac{2}{T}+\frac{2}{3 T}=\\
\frac{6+2}{3 T}=\frac{8}{3 T}
\end{array}$$
Thank you.

Comment: please include your working.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I have now done so.

Comment: You say you have only two random variables $G$ and $U$ but then you introduce many more random variables $G_{2j}$ and $U_{2i-1}$.  How do these relate to $G$ and $U$? Are you really saying that $\{U_1, G_2, U_3, G_4, ...\}$ are mutually independent and that $\{U_{2i-1}\}$ are i.i.d. with the same distribution as $U$, and $\{G_{2j}\}$ are i.i.d. with the same distribution as $G$?  I don't think you really mean "$G_{2j}$ means that the $2j$th term is the random variable $G$" since that would mean $$\sum_{j=1}^{T/2}G_{2j} = \sum_{j=1}^{T/2}G = (T/2)G$$

Comment: @Michael That is precisely what I mean.

Comment: In the case $G_{2j}=G$ and $U_{2i-1}=U$ for all $i$, you would get $$Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^{T/2}G_{2j} +\sum_{i=1}^{T/2}U_{2i-1}\right) = Var((T/2)(G+U))= (T/2)^2(1+1/3)$$ which would make the answer considerably different than what you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

Good job, your answer is correct, we do not need the properties that they are uniform or normal.

We just need their variance and the fact that they are independent to perform the computation.

$$\begin{array}{l}
\left(\frac{2}{T}\right)^{2} \sum_{j=1}^{T / 2} \operatorname{var}\left(G_{2 j}\right)+\left(\frac{2}{T}\right)^{2} \sum_{i=1}^{T / 2} \operatorname{var}\left(U_{2 i-1}\right)\\=
\left(\frac{2}{T}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{T}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{2}{T}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{1}{3} \frac{T}{2}\right)=\frac{2}{T}+\frac{2}{T} \frac{1}{\color{blue}3}=\frac{2}{T}+\frac{2}{3 T}=\\
\frac{6+2}{3 T}=\frac{8}{3 T}
\end{array}$$

As $T$ increases, the variance decreases.

Assumption: not only that $G$ and $U$ are independent, we also neethat each pair of the random variable being independent